# The method 'initialiazeNotification' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: initialiazeNotification()

Tags: flutter, null, notifications

i have a problem with null stuff, my error is "The method 'initialiazeNotification' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: initialiazeNotification()"

I tried to delete code in NotifyHelper class step by step to find the error, but nothing works

this is my main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: Themes.light,
      darkTheme: Themes.dark,
      themeMode: ThemeService().theme,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );}}
```

this is my homepage block where I initialized all the veriables, classes and finctions

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  var notifyHelper;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    notifyHelper.initialiazeNotification();
    notifyHelper=NotifyHelper();
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.requestPermission();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(),
      body: const Column(
        children: [
          Text("Theme Data",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  _appBar(){
    return AppBar(
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          ThemeService().switchTheme();
          notifyHelper.displayNotification(
            title:'Тема изменилась' ,
            body: Get.isDarkMode?'black':'light'
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.nightlight_round,
        size: 20,),
      ),
      actions: const [
        Icon(Icons.person,
          size: 20,),
        SizedBox(width: 20,)
      ],);}}
```

this is notification blick where I tried to do local notifications for my app

```
class NotifyHelper {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  initializeNotification() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('appicon');
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(

            requestAlertPermission: false,
            requestBadgePermission: false,
            requestSoundPermission: false,
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);
  }

  displayNotification({required String? title, required String? body}) async {
    print("doing test");
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'Хуйня',
        importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'You change your theme',
      'You changed your theme back !',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'It could be anything you pass',
    );
  }

  void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse? notificationResponse) async {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse?.payload;
    if (payload != null) {
      print ("notification payload: $payload");
    } else {print('Notification done'); }
    Get.to(() => Container(color: Colors.white,));
  }



  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
    Get.dialog(Text('welcome to flutter'));
  }
}
```

I tried to delete code step by step, added ? everywher in veriables and functions, but nothing works

Comment: I ve just eddited my code, could you check it up?

Comment: i have found a solution, we need to initialize the async function in main module, I dont know why, but it works, can anybody explain me please, why I can do it only through main?